# How to make cron run every 2 hours and 11 minutes on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I use `*/58 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f ....` to run on every 58 minutes. But I need to build a cron that can run every 2 hours and 11 minutes. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It's very difficult to do that. Is it possible to do it every hour?

Comment: This is a strange requirement. Where does this requirement come from?

Comment: @David well maybe could be every 3 hours.

Comment: Three hours: `* */03 * * * /usr/bin/php -f ....`

Comment: @David, can i do * */3 * * * instead of this one?

Comment: That would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `at`. Once called at system start with `at -f /path/script.sh "now + 131minutes"` it would start /path/script.sh after 131 minutes uptime. Then, in /path/script.sh, insert another invocation of `at`. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/at

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
*/58 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f ....
```

doesn't run  every 58 minutes.  Just as `*/5` in the minutes field runs at every minute after the hour that's a multiple of 5, `*/58` runs at every minute after the hour that's a multiple of 58.  In other words, the job will run at 00:00, 00:58, 01:00, 01:58, 02:00, 02:58, etc.; the interval between two runs alternates between 58 minutes and 2 minutes.

There are probably tools other than cron that will do what you want.  But if you want to use cron for this, you can have a job that runs every minutes:

```
 * * * * * your-wrapper-script /usr/bin/php -f ...
```

and implement `your-wrapper-script` so it executes its arguments only if the current time is a multiple of 131 minutes (2 hours, 11 minutes).

This Perl script should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $now = time;
my $minutes = int($now/60);
if ($minutes % 131 == 0) {
    system @ARGV; # NOTE: No error detection
}
```